# What is the best framework or method to take a set of stand-alone HTML pages and make it an iPad app?

Tags: ipad, html, frameworks, uiwebview

I have been developing a simple app using HTML pages that are interlinked.  They will be using some form of data persistence.  I have not decided yet.  They will be displayed on an iPad in both landscape and portrait modes.

I could wrap them in a UIWebView and roll my own app that way, but to me it seems that others must have come across this requirement before and there might be a simple framework to do this.

I don't need any special access to location data, accelerometers etc.  Just plain HTML, some CSS and Javascript.  The most complex of which will need to store a series of name value pairs (circa. 150 items) that will need to be available to all pages within the application.  I have no need to call the Javascript from the app or vis versa.

I will need to insert inApp purchasing in future to the application, whereby I will load a larger set of HTML files.  It might be nice to be able to trigger that from inside the HTML pages but that is not necessarily a deal breaker.

There are a number of frameworks for writing apps in HTML5 etc. and converting.  I don't really need this either.

But I would rather use some framework that will take the lessons learned by others and let me deploy my app on an iPad with minimal risk.

Can anyone give me advice regarding the best framework for this use case?

Thanking you in advance,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I would use [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/).  [It works on the iPad](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/25124206/iPad) no problem.

You can use the camera and accelerometer and all that with [phonegap-plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins).

I am using it on a few iPad projects, and since you can use HTML/CSS/JavaScript, you can pretty much just configure phonegap with your web address and your web app is now an iPad app (that or just add static html files to the phonegap project directory).  Then it's just 'modify the design and layout HTML/CSS'.

Comment: Thanks viatropos, I am likely to go with phone gap because I can see someone else who has a similar use case working well on phonegap.